# How to fix: Unrecognized command error in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Hi everyone!
I wrote a script that worked in the past, but suddenly it does not work and I have no idea why.
Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script gets damage seq bed files of 4 nucleotides and filters only those with dipyrimidins in 2-3 position.
_pwd=$PWD
#hg-19 ref genome.
genome_path="/hg_19_ref_genome.fa" 
#Scans all the damage seq given bed files.
for bedFile in $_pwd/*.bed
do
  #Removes duplicates lines.
  sort -u -o $bedFile  $bedFile 
  #Sorts the files according to chromosome and coordinates. 
  sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -o $bedFile  $bedFile 
  name=`basename $bedFile`
  #Adjusts the fasta file name. 
  faName="${name%.bed*}.fa"    
  bedtools getfasta -s -fi $genome_path -bed $bedFile -name -fo $_pwd/fasta_files/$faName #Gets the sequence itself.
done

#Scans all the obtained fasta files.
for faFile in $_pwd/fasta_files/*.fa
do
  name=`basename $faFile`
  faOutput="${name}"
  bedOutput="${name%.fa*}.bed"
  #Filters the files for getting only those which contain dypirimidne in 2-3 columns. 
  cat $faFile  |\
  paste - -  |\
  awk 'toupper(substr($2,2,2)) ~ /^(TT|TC|CT|CC)$/' |\
  tr "\t" "\n" |\
  tee $_pwd/filtered_fasta/$faOutput |\ 
  awk -F '[>():-]' '/^>/ {printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",$4,$5,$6,$2,$2,$7);}' > $_pwd/filtered_bed/$bedOutput 
done
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
line 30:  : command not found
```

where line 30 is this line:

```
tee $_pwd/filtered_fasta/$faOutput |\
```

I have no idea why this error occurs, it worked fine before.
I really hope someone can help me with that issue.

**UPDATE:** I deleted all the '' and it works fine now.

Comment: FWIW, the backslashes after the pipe characters are not necessary. As long as the pipe character is the last character on a line, the shell knows to use the next line as the next pipe segment. But .. try running your script through http://shellcheck.net. You'll get tips for many improvements which may make debugging easier.

Comment: The error is consistent with that line ending with a carriage return (`\r`).

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I should believe that you've pasted your script correctly, there is a character in line 30 after the backslash `\`.

The Bash itself is telling you name of the unknown command:

```
line 30:  : command not found
```

The thing between `:` is name of command that Bash was unable to recognize and this thing is  - a white space.

As suggested in comments, remove the backslashes `\` after pipe `|` and make sure that the pipe character is the last one in line. This will improve readability.

Also, good editor can show white spaces ([example for Sublime Text](https://coderwall.com/p/s_ahiq/sublime-text-always-show-whitespace)). Enabling it will show you such mistakes.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't see that. :-)